# Camel CSV Transformation to Java Object

Tags: apache-camel

I have a large CSV file containing a set of users. I'm looking for a simple way to read the file, map to a Java Object and pass this Object to a processor which will perform some operations on the Object.
So I have marked a Java bean with annotations that represent the CSV file:

```
@CsvRecord(separator = ",")
public class User {
    @DataField(pos = 1)
    private String username;
    @DataField(pos = 2)
    private String group;

}
```

Then I have started to code a Camel Route, however I cannot find out how to pass the CSV as Java Object to an endpoint:

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    final DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat("com.sample.model");
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("file:/usr/camel/in?noop=true").
            unmarshal(bindy)
            .to("??????");
        }
});
```

The target endpoint should be a java class which received the User Object. Is is possible to do that ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an instance of a `Processor` to process the POJO:

```
    Processor myProcessor = new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            // do something here
        }
    };

    from("file:/usr/camel/in?noop=true")
    .unmarshal(bindy)
    .process(myProcessor);
```

**Solution 2:** you can use a bean. First, add this "bean" class:

```
public class MyBean {
    public void process(List<String> list) {
        System.out.println("list contains " + list.size() + " elements.");
    }
}
```

And now, [Camel Bean Binding](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html) takes the "In" body on the exchange and supplies it as a parameter to your bean (avoiding the whole `exchange.getIn().getBody()` part).

```
from("file:/usr/camel/in?noop=true")
.unmarshal(bindy)
.bean(new MyBean())
```

If you want to use a different argument to your bean, you can use a method call with a `simple` expression, like this:

```
.bean(new MyBean(), "process(${body.get(0).etc...})")
```

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented a simple processor, however in order to retrieve the Object I had to dig into the Body, then into the ArrayList of data which in turn contains HashMaps. Is there a simpler way to retrieve the POJO from a Processor ?
`public class SimpleProcessor implements Processor {
 public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
  ArrayList<HashMap> list = (ArrayList) exchange.getIn().getBody();
  for (HashMap map:list) {
   Iterator iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
   while (iter.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println("user " + iter.next());
  }
}`
  
   
 }
}

Comment: No worries, and good luck with Camel, it's an awesome framework once you get to use it for a good while :)